# Where can I get the Wild Wasteland gauss rifle?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have the Wild Wasteland perk activated and I got the alien gun, but I still want a gauss rifle. Are there any other locations in the game where I can get one?

Answer (score 4):

From [the Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gauss_rifle_%28Fallout:_New_Vegas%29), here is a list of rifle locations

Hidden Valley bunker - can be purchased from Knight Torres after following the quest lines. Also, many of the paladins in Brotherhood T-51b power armor have this weapon.

Silver Rush, Freeside - sometimes sold at higher levels.

Carried by Father Elijah

Big MT - can be found on Y-17 trauma override harnesses, most notably near the X-7a "Left Field" artillery launch

Brewer's beer bootlegging - often found in a locked gun cabinet in the cellar. There is a key underneath the Big Book of Science in the other room, otherwise, the locker has a Lockpick skill of 75 needed.